# How to count and print the inbetween range from random list

Tags: python, list, random, import, range

Q1.  Write a program to generate 10 integer random numbers in the range [10, 50].

```
import random
mylist=[]

for i in range (10):
x=random.randint(10,50)
mylist.append(x)

print(mylist)
```

i don't know if this correct

```
output: [41, 40, 36, 49, 14, 12, 11, 22, 43, 25]
```

this the output because it's random everytime so this is where i don't know what to do.

Q2. How many of these numbers fall in the ranges 10-24.

the answer in this case should be :

```
output: 4
```

because there are 4 number in between ranges 10 to 24 on mylist output above which is 14,12,11, and 22

what code i need to write to get the [output:4]?

Comment: What have you tried? Think about what type output is. It is a list. You want to filter a list, then count the number of elements in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your code to create random numbers is correct.
Try:

```
len([i for i in mylist if 10<=i<=24])
```

This finds the numbers between 10 and 24 in the list (including 10 and 24. Omit the = if you dont want to include 10 and 24).
Simplified:

```
count = 0
for i in mylist:
    if 10<=i<=24:
        count +=1
#now find its length
print(count)
```

Comment: I think OP was expected to use an explicit loop.

Comment: You do not need list in the 2nd case, just a counter would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

```
print(len(filter(lambda x: 10<=x<=24, mylist)))
```